How do you modify values in a solidjs store using a 2d array?
If I have a store like so...
  const [store, setStore] = createStore([
    [
      {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 'a',
      }
    ]
  ])

How would I update the value of foo (at [0][0]) to be 2 using setStore?

Why are you using a nested array? Which element's foo do you want to update, the first, all, some at a specific index? Do you know how to do it for a non-nested array?

To update the value you use setStore like so...
setStore(0, 0, 'foo', 2);

